# Strategy for Reporting on JMS Activity

Tags: reporting, jms, message-queue, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

The answer to this question may be obvious to someone with more experience in data-warehousing and BI, but I am looking for some guidance.

I'm building a system that uses multiple JMS queues to process millions of messages per day.  I need visibility into the activity of these queues, so that I can create reports like..."Yesterday at 11:01am, how many messages entered queue A that had the word 'Foo' in them?"

To make matters worse, I have about 200k words I need to run this report on, for every minute of every day, across several queues, each processing millions of messages per day.

When I think of implementing a custom solution for this, I start going down a wormhole into a pit of despair.  Surely I can't be the only person who has ever faced this problem before.

Anybody got any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general for any MOM problem I suggest this [site](http://www.eaipatterns.com) and the book it is based on.

In particular check out the [Message Store](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageStore.html) pattern and possibly the [Detour](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Detour.html)